# Jquery date time format

Tags: jquery

I found a date and time on jsfiddle i have tried to change the display with no luck.

it currently displays like this

08/30/2016 at 7:48 AM

But I need it to display like this

Sun 2016 28, August 13:23 hrs

I am not sure how to go about it.

```
function updatingClock(selector, type) {
        function currentDate() {
            var currentDate = new Date;
            var Day = currentDate.getDate();
            if (Day < 10) {
                Day = '0' + Day;
            } //end if
            var Month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
            if (Month < 10) {
                Month = '0' + Month;
            } //end if
            var Year = currentDate.getFullYear();
            var fullDate = Month + '/' + Day + '/' + Year;
            return fullDate;
        } //end current date function

        function currentTime() {
            var currentTime = new Date;
            var Minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            if (Minutes < 10) {
                Minutes = '0' + Minutes;
            }
            var Hour = currentTime.getHours();
            if (Hour > 12) {
                Hour -= 12;
            } //end if
            var Time = Hour + ':' + Minutes;
            if (currentTime.getHours() <= 12) {
                Time += ' AM';
            } //end if
            if (currentTime.getHours() > 12) {
                Time += ' PM';
            } //end if
            return Time;
        } // end current time function


        function updateOutput() {
            var output;
            if (type == 'time') {
                output = currentTime();
                if ($(selector).text() != output) {
                    $(selector).text(output);
                } //end if
            } //end if
            if (type == 'date') {
                output = currentDate();
                if ($(selector).text() != output) {
                    $(selector).text(output);
                } //end if
            } //end if
            if (type == 'both') {
                output = currentDate() + ' at ' + currentTime();
                if ($(selector).text() != output) {
                    $(selector).text(output);
                } //end if
            } //end if
        }//end update output function
        updateOutput();
        window.setInterval(function() {
            updateOutput();
        }, 1000); //run update every 1 second
    } // end updating clock function
    updatingClock('#date-time', 'both');
```

Comment: Have you considered to use a lib like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: mpf82 wouldn't even know where to begin with it.. just want something simple.

Comment: May I suggest in the future, including the fiddle in your question as it would be a good reference for us to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and use below format than you can append 'hrs' to result string

```
moment(yourDateTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss');
```

Comment: jekin Kalariya Ive downloaded moment.js but not sure what to do with the code. I am new to js

Comment: just in clude it in your code with <script> tag and use above code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>

Comment: I know how to include a js file but how do you get the time to display where you want

Comment: jekin Kalariya is there anyway to stop it from not displaying? when you click it it takes a long time to load.

Comment: it was just beacuse i was display real time with second, now I remove interval so it will not delay check this link for that   https://jsfiddle.net/thfcyn7k/